# upstart logging output enabled

Tags: logging, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, upstart

Except doing explicit logging instructions like suggested in http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Debugging, is there a way to enable output of what is happening with upstart?

- What event is raised
- What service changed its status (started/stopped/dead)
- What signal were emmited
- what output a service produced while starting

Comment: Perhaps this question might be more appropriate on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: It's relative to both server and desktop... Should I close this one and re-open in serverfault?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, I've found one way to get it :

```
$ sudo initctl log-priority        # gives the actual (default) logging level
$ sudo initctl log-priority --help # gives available logging levels
$ sudo initctl log-priority info # is enough to get :
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog        # - log of upstart events
$ tail -f /var/log/boot.log      # - log of services output
```

Comment: hey! Ubuntu 11.10 here and there is no /var/log/boot.log for me, just /var/log/boot. That doesn't produce any process output though, i tried `echo 'hi'` and it's not showing up in /var/log/boot. Any tips?

Comment: @rdrey: /var/log/kern.log maybe?

Comment: @AtilaRomero maybe ;) I actually don't remember this question/comment at all, sorry.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.10 now, why I still cannot get the log following your steps?

Comment: You may need to add `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` to rsyslogd's config, as detailed here: http://askubuntu.com/a/490900/297973

Answer (score 19):

In newer versions, you can find the upstart logs at:

```
/var/log/upstart
```

It has a log for each process it tries to start.

Comment: FTR: That is true for 12.04 and 14.04 but not for 10.04.

Answer (score 8):

`initctl log-priority info` logs events, but ignores the program output.

If the program output is important to you, I think the complementary solution is to use logger in your init script:

```
script
    myawesomeprog 2>&1 | logger -t myawesomeprog
end script
```

Because it's better to use syslog than manually manage `/var/log`, like http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Debugging suggests (in 08/2012).

Comment: Doesn't give any output for me using: `su -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS" $ES_USER 2>&1 | logger -t elasticsearch`